Putting balls into urns, with a tie-break criteria
Consider the classic problem of placing n balls into n urns. All balls (resp. all urns) have a strict order of which urn (resp. ball) they prefer. All orders are drawn uniformly at random.
Suppose each ball into its most favorite bin at the same time. This is round 1.
If more than one ball is thrown into the same bin, the one most preferred by the urn gets in and all others are thrown away by an umpire.
Those balls will be thrown again in a later round.
Note that there the probability that the probability that an urn remains empty in the first round is
$$\left[1 - \frac{1}{n}\right]^n\approx \frac{1}{e}$$
Now, the remaining balls are thrown into the second urn in round 2. A ball cannot be thrown to an urn that it was thrown before, but it may be that the ball is thrown to an urn that is currently filled with a ball. If the urn prefers the new ball over the one currently in the urn, the umpire will allow it to go into the urn, and the previously inserted ball will be thrown to a different urn at a later round.
In the second round, there are $n/e$ balls that were thrown away by the umpire and that still need to be thrown. They are thrown into the second most favorite bin. The probability that they hit a non-empty urn is (I think)
$$\frac{(n-n/e-1)}{n}$$
and the probability that their number is closest to that in the ball already inside the urn is ?
I am interested in how many balls end up in their most favorite urn after the procedure concludes, i.e. after all urns are filled with exactly one ball. This number must be less than $n-e/n$ and I believe must be $n/e$, but have no idea how to show it. Ideas are most welcome.
the problem is very similar to a previous question asked here: Sequential allocation of $n$ balls into $n$ urns

“More” baseball? When did you ask about baseball before? I don’t see any mention of baseball in the textbook. What makes a baseball player “corresponding”?

What is the distribution? Is it continuous or discrete? Are the numbers on urns and balls all independent of all the other numbers? How do you determine at the end if the number of the urn is “closest” to the ball inside: do you mean the urn’s number is closer to the ball than other urns are, the ball is closer to the urn than other balls are, the urn and ball are closer than any other urn and ball, or something else?

How is this following the procedure in the book? Page 95 seems to be about throwing balls into bins and allowing a bin to contain multiple balls, not redistributing the extra balls into other bins. Moreover, I didn’t see where they put numbers on anything.

“If many balls are thrown into the same bin, … .” How many is “many”? Is it any number greater than $1$?

I have provided clarifications to your questions. The distribution of numbers is not important, as I have stated. All we need is that there is a complete order over which is the closest ball for each urn, and viceversa.

OK, so the remaining places that says “closest to” mean “most favorite.” And rather than one random number, each ball and bin is assigned a unique identifier from $1$ to $n$ and a random permutation of the integers from $1$ to $n$. But the distribution matters. For example, consider $n=1000$ and a distribution where with probability $0.999999$ the $k$th favorite is $k$ and with probability $0.000001$ it is $n-k+1$. Then most likely all balls want to be in urn $1$ and only one ball will be.

I am sorry for the vague question. I guess I wanted to say iid uniform distribution.

That sounds a lot better. Now it’s a math question.

Your algorithm seems to be 'Gales and Shapley's algorithm'. Maybe with this keywords you will find more informations.

This is neither an exact formula nor a precise proof, but gives somewhat of an answer: the expected number of balls that end in their favorite urn is $o(n)$.
To argue this, fix some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. In the question, it was argued that after the first round, for large enough $n$, about a $\frac{1}{e}$ part of the urns are left after the first round (with high probability). With the same logic, in the second round, any of the open urns has about a $(1-\frac{1}{n-1})^{\frac{n}{e}}\approx e^{-\frac{1}{e}}$ chance of staying empty. Without proof, we state that for the first $c$ rounds, if $c$ is constant, then as $n\to\infty$, with high probability a certain fraction of urns is empty for each round, and a certain fraction of balls is kicked out in each round.
In particular, there is a fixed number of rounds $c$ for which, in the limit, with high probability the fraction of empty urns after $c$ rounds is close to $\frac{1}{e^{k}}$.
Now sum the number of leftover balls from rounds $1,2\ldots,c$, call this sum $S$. How many should they be? We claim $S\approx kn$: since $n$ is large, since all the distributions are independent, the probability of an urn being empty is basically just the probability that all the $kn$ balls went into another urn, so it should be about $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{kn}\approx e^{-k}$.
Now consider an individual urn $u$ in the first $c$ rounds. In all likeliness, it sees $k$ balls enter it. If some ball $b$ had $u$ as its favorite urn, the probability that this ball stays in the urn is the probability that ball $b$ is ranked better by $u$ than the other balls entering it. So $b$ has about a $\frac{1}{k}$ chance of staying in the urn. Since we can pick $k$ arbitrarily large, the probability for a ball of staying in its favorite urn goes to $0$, so the expected number of balls in favorite urns is $o(n)$.
